# std::is_same returns false when comparing std::tuple_element and decltype(std::get)

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype

I can't find a similar question...

I think there are two "easy" ways of getting the type of the I^th element of a tuple at compile time (correct me if I am wrong):

- `using TI1 = typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type;`
- `using TI2 = decltype(std::get<I>(Tuple{}));`

In fact, if we print the types of each of these via `typeid(...).name()`, these return the same value.

However... `std::is_same` returns false when I compare these:

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OkRfhCVjbb3diQ64)

Is this expected? why?

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<float,double>;
constexpr size_t I = 0;
static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type,
                           decltype(std::get<I>(Tuple{}))>::value, "different types" );
```

Comment: `get` probably returns an rvalue reference, slap `std::remove_reference_t` onto it.

Comment: I am bad and I feel bad. You are correct sir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::get(std::tuple)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) returns reference; that means using [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) on it you'll get a reference type.

> a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields
>   `T&&`;
>   b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields
>   `T&`;
>   c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype
>   yields `T`.

For this case, the return type of `std::get<I>(Tuple{})` is an rvalue-reference, then `std::get<I>(Tuple{})` is an [xvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue),

> a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

then `decltype(std::get<I>(Tuple{}))` will be `T&&`, i.e. `float&&`; which is different with `typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type` (i.e. `float`).

Using [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) you could get what you want. e.g.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type,
                           std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<I>(Tuple{}))>>::value, "different types" );
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l2YxpaZ8EH2C5Dby)

And about why [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) gives the same result,

(emphasis mine)

> 1) Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type type. **If type is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type.**

That means `typeid(float&&) == typeid(float)` is always `true`.

Comment: I prefer to use `std::decay` in cases like these, even if removing reference might be sufficient